# partially flatten a nested list

Tags: list, haskell, nested-lists

Is there a function in the Prelude that removes the external "[]"?  For example, in this situation:

```
f [[[1,0,0]],[[1,0,0]]] = [[1,0,0],[1,0,0]]
```

Answer (score 7):

I believe `concat :: [[a]] -> [a]` does what you are looking for

And remember that you can always use [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=[[a]]+-%3E+[a]) to find functions based on what arguments they would return or receive

Comment: Here's how you can find functions that might be useful. First, think about what the type signature for the function would be: `[[a]] -> [a]`. In other words, it takes a list of lists of something (in your case the "something" is another list), and returns a list. Now go to Hoogle (http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) or Hayoo (http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html) and type in that type signature. You'll get a list of all functions that have that type.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `concat` which flattens a list of lists into a single list:

```
concat [[[1,0,0]],[[1,0,0]]]
```

`concat` is also `join` in Control.Monad for lists so you could use that:

```
join [[[1,0,0]],[[1,0,0]]]
```